# Providing a status update when "ENTER" is pressed, while program is working

Tags: multithreading, perl, signals, ipc

I have a PERL script that loops through and calls a binary with a different argument.  I am using IPC::Run.  I would like when the user presses a key such as "ENTER" a status message is displayed such as

"Currently working on 14 of 28 total scripts (50% complete)"

My script is as follows:

```
    foreach my $file (@files) {

        $file =~ s/$file_dir//;

        #Run the test case, store the output in $stdout 
        run [ "php", "PROGRAM.phar", "$file" ], ">", \my $stdout;

                    print LOG_FILE "Return code $?\n";
                    print LOG_FILE "Output: $stdout");

    }
```

Basically how would I interrupt the binary in order to display my status message?

Comment: How would I interrupt the binary in order to display the status message, while the binary is running?  Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Why not just print the status on each iteration?

Comment: I could do that, but I prefer a user hitting a key to display updated status.  Similar to how you can press enter to force "top" to refresh.

Comment: do you mean the binary has status of its task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correct this usage of IPC::Run is not multithreaded. It will execute the commands one by one and it is not possible to print messages because there is only one process.

Like:

```
  use Parallel::ForkManager;

  $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($MAX_PROCESSES);
  my $input;

  foreach $data (@all_data) {
    # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
    my $pid = $pm->start and next;

    ... do some work with $data in the child process ...

    $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
    chomp($input= <STDIN>);
    print "Some statistics\n" if $input =~ m!\n!;

  }
```

Regards,